# How to pull image from custom docker registry with golang?

Tags: go, docker

Using docker sources how to pull image from custom registry? As a result of using such code

```
// Prepare auth registry for usage
func (app *App) PrepareRegistry() error {
    app.AuthConfig = types.AuthConfig{
        Username:      Username,
        Password:      Password,
        ServerAddress: DefaultServer,
    }

    resp, err := app.Client.RegistryLogin(context.Background(), app.AuthConfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    if resp.IdentityToken != "" {
        app.AuthConfig.IdentityToken = resp.IdentityToken
    }

    app.AuthConfigEncoded, err = command.EncodeAuthToBase64(app.AuthConfig)
    return err
}

func (app *App) ImagePull() error {

    opts := types.ImagePullOptions{
        All:            true,
        RegistryAuth: app.AuthConfigEncoded,
        PrivilegeFunc: registryAuthentication(app.Name),
    }
    responseBody, err := app.Client.ImagePull(context.Background(), app.Name, opts)
    defer responseBody.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am still getting the error

```
Login Succeeded
panic: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/shalakhin/blender/tags/list: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

While ServerAddress is registry.gitlab.com, not registry-1.docker.io

Comment: Where are all of these functions/types defined, like `app.Client`, what libraries are you using? A [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be needed.

Comment: I use docker source code. I have App struct that holds docker Client, app name (we can say image name) etc.

Comment: @shalakhin have you solved this? also may i know the docker source code you're using (github link)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check identity token? That might cause an authentication problem.

A suggestion:
[Docker client](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient/)

This works fine, as I can see you did not specify the **endpoint**. I think you should add this info.

Answer (score 0):

```
authConfig := types.AuthConfig{
    Username: "username",
    Password: "password",
}
encodedJSON, err := json.Marshal(authConfig)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
authStr := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(encodedJSON)

out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, "alpine", types.ImagePullOptions{RegistryAuth: authStr})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```